# Is there a way to update custom packages with composer?

Tags: 8, composer

The project is using Drupal 8 composer template to manage dependencies. Some of the packages are defined locally to look like Drupal modules and be installed in a specific location.

An example could be found [here](https://github.com/sisuloome/drupal/blob/master/composer.json#L20)

The issue is that Composer does not store the data about these packages and their version within the .lock file. This means that there does not seem to be a meaningful way to update those custom defined modules with composer itself.

Is there a better way than just writing some custom script, probably relates to some post install procedure that would just visit all of the subdirectories that could possibly be these custom modules and would issue the `git pull`? Or is there a way to just force composer to reinstall these packages on each `composer install` run?

We fully control the codebase for these packages/modules and master branches should be safe to use.

Comment: Aren't your custom modules a part of your site repo?

Comment: They should be. But I can see a use case for upstream work. See the composer docs on how to maintain repository endpoints.

Comment: You can put each module into its own repo. That only makes sense if the module is going to be shared with another project.

Comment: Some of those modules are to be reused in other projects. Keeping everything in one repo is not a good solution in the long run. The idea was to manage those with Composer as normal dependencies. We could move some of them into a modules on the Drupal infrastructure. That should allow better management of versions, yet it would not allow fast updated to a possibly unstable codebase.

I will check out the Composer docs on the matter, but I guessed that it has already been resolved by the teams using Drupal.

Comment: There is some info over at StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784809/how-to-use-a-specific-tag-version-with-composer-and-a-private-git-repository

Comment: The referenced questions is useful for setting it up, but current setup is working well enough, except for updating the already installed packages. The issue is that it does not pull the latest changes from the repository.

Tagging versions and changing the composer.json to reflect that is one possibility that seems to be available. That should probably work with the general flow of logic that package manager has.

Still, it would be useful to know if current approach is even viable to keep the special modules/packages/repositories constantly in sync with the specified branch.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve, but in case I've understood ok: remove the existing `package` repos, replace them with `{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/sisuloome/h5p_google_analytics.git" }` etc. Add a composer.json to each repo and commit (it's not important to maintain a valid "version" in those files, the package name is important though). Run `composer require sisuloome/h5p_google_analytics:dev-master` etc in your project. Now, in theory, you can run `composer update sisuloome/h5p_google_analytics` etc to update the packages to master as normal

Comment: Also make sure each project's composer.json contains `"type": "drupal-module"`

Answer (score 0):

You do this with requiring the [Composer Merge Plugin](https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin) in your Drupal project's `composer.json` and then define in which additional locations it should look for `composer.json` files to be merged.

> Composer Merge Plugin is intended to allow easier dependency management for applications which ship a `composer.json` file and expect some deployments to install additional Composer managed libraries. It does this by allowing the application's top level `composer.json` file to provide a list of optional additional configuration files. When Composer is run it will parse these files and merge their configuration settings into the base configuration. This combined configuration will then be used when downloading additional libraries and generating the autoloader.